# Rcov coverage changes drastically with -xrefs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rcov

My current Ruby on Rails project does testing via rcov (specifically, [relevance rcov](http://github.com/relevance/rcov), and we have a pretty high standard (we fail the build if we have < 95% code coverage).

We use the following command to test this:

```
rcov_cmd = "rcov --rails --text-summary \
            --include #{included_dirs} \
            --exclude #{excluded_dirs} \
            --aggregate #{coverage_dir}/coverage.data \
            --output #{coverage_dir} \
```

Today I found some code that registers green (having run) in the rcov reports. Homever, I can prove that this code isn't getting run (I raise an exception in the beginning of the function, and my unit tests pass)

I did some research and found the --xrefs flag for rcov, which I thought would add all the callers for each line in the rcov reports.

I changed the rcov command to:

```
rcov_cmd = "rcov --rails --text-summary --xrefs \
        --include #{included_dirs} \
        --exclude #{excluded_dirs} \
        --aggregate #{coverage_dir}/coverage.data \
        --output #{coverage_dir} \
```

(notice the added `--xrefs` flag).

Instead of additional callsite information, I instead have my test coverage go from 96% to 48%.

Does --xrefs change the kind of analysis how rcov does? (I thought it would just gather callsite information). How is this different / better from the first command?
(I've seen the unit test coverage drop if there's a failing unit test, and I know that the coverage percentage can drop if there's an error in the run, but it looks good to me)

Comment: Have you tried with just `--callsites` and no `--xrefs` to determine whether it is actually the included callsites information that is causing the difference? Might narrow the problem down a little.

Comment: I replaced --xrefs and --callsites and saw the same drop in test coverage

Answer (score 1):

From [rcov manual](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/rcov/):

```
--[no-]callsites
    Show callsites in generated XHTML report. (somewhat slower; disabled by default)
--[no-]xrefs
    Generate fully cross-referenced report. (includes --callsites)
```

From [Rcov CallSiteAnalyzer Class](http://docs.rdocul.us/rcov/master/classes/Rcov/CallSiteAnalyzer.html)

```
A CallSiteAnalyzer can be used to obtain information about:

    * where a method is defined ("defsite")
    * where a method was called from ("callsite")
```

Having this analyze rcov can provide more accurate coverage information in cost of longer execution.